# How can I change the properties of an Export stream at runtime?

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-streams

The [Dynamic application composition](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/streams/v3r1/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.streams.spl-language-specification.doc/doc/dynamicappcomposition.html) topic says that

> Properties can also be added, updated, or removed at runtime, and so can subscriptions. The compile-time properties and subscriptions just serve as initial settings.

but it doesn't say how to do that.  So, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the operator that exports the stream, call

```
setOutputPortExportProperties({property1_name=value, property2_name=value, ...},
  portNumber);
```

In the operator that imports the stream, call

```
setInputPortImportSubscription(subscription_string, portNumber);
```

SPL sample project 042_dynamic_import_export_api_at_work provides an example.

Comment: This post on Streamsdev discusses changing properties in depth:https://developer.ibm.com/streamsdev/docs/changing-connections-runtime-export-import/